# Caller does not have required permission to use project demo-project

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to connect to Google Cloud Vision with Firebase functions in the emulator suite but i get a "PERMISSION DENIED" error when i call it.

Code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { logger } = require("firebase-functions");
const vision = require("@google-cloud/vision");
const { getStorage } = require("firebase-admin/storage");

exports.bucketTesting = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const fileBucket = await getStorage().bucket().getFiles();
  const bucketName = getStorage().bucket().name;
  const allFiles = fileBucket[0];

  const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

  for (const file of allFiles) {
    const [result] = await client.labelDetection(
      `gs://${bucketName}/${file.name}`
    );
    console.log(result);
  }

  res.send({ bucketFiles: bucketName });
});
```

> ⚠  Google API requested!
>
> - URL: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
> - Be careful, this may be a production service. ⚠  functions: Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Caller does not have required permission
>   to use project demo-project. Grant the caller the
>   roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer role, or a custom role with
>   the serviceusage.services.use permission, by visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=demo-project
>   and then retry. Propagation of the new permission may take a few
>   minutes.

I followed the link and nothing changes.

projectID in `firebase.js` is "demo-project" so i'm guessing that my GCP account can't recognise it since this isn't the projectID for my real project in my GCP account.
Do i change projectID to my real project name or create a new project with projectID of "demo-project" in GCP. Pretty sure these are not the only alternatives.

Comment: Change the project ID in the configuration. The project ID are unique across the globe, you can't create a project named demo-project if it already exists.

Comment: App Engine default service account (<YOUR_PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com>).
Ensure it has the roles/vision.editor role. If not, add it.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, are you saying i must change projectID alone in the ```firebase.js```? Change that configuration for emulator?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that, and with the project ID (not the project Name, It's the same by default, but you can change the project name, not the project ID.)